# How do I make kotlin composable update when a global value changes

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, composable

I am learning the basics of Kotlin and Composables. My use case is very simple, I have a global variable:

```
var globalValue : Int = 1
```

Then I have this composable:

```
@Composable
fun SomeView(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
  ...some Text() printing globalValue
```

When I change the value of the `globalValue` I would like SomeView() to get called.

I have tried the `by remember` and using the `globalValue` as parameter to the Composable, but I seem to miss the point, nothing gets updated.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Check https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state-hoisting

Comment: Thanks Diego, I read it and watched the video before, but it's such a complex example, not at all down to the point. I would need a simple code example of how to bind to the globalValue.

Comment: Doing your homework really pays off. If you are new to kotlin like me, take your time with these great classes! This one is pretty much answering my question:
https://developer.android.com/courses/pathways/android-basics-compose-unit-2-pathway-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `State` to update the composable when the value of the variable changes, So you can simply use `mutableStateOf` like below:

```kotlin
val globalValue = mutableStateOf(1)
```

So you need read and write to this state using `value` property for example to set this variable to 10 you can write this:

```kotlin
globalValue.value = 10
```

if you want to use your globalVariable without calling `.value` you can simply use delegation for the property using `by` keyword.

```kotlin
var globalValue by mutableStateOf(1)
```

Now you can set the variable as an normal `Int` variable.

Comment: I wouldn't combine `var` with State unless you're using it as a delegate.

Comment: @Tenfour04 sorry but i didn't understand what you mean. if you need to use pure `Integer` you can use `by` keyword for delegation then simply use your globalVariable as an `Integer` variable

Comment: I'm saying a State property should be read-only because there's never a reason to change it to a different State instance.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Oh, Yes it was a mistake. Thank you. I edited it.

Comment: Thank you a zillion Mohammad! It was as I suspected, too simple for me to grasp. :-D My mistake was to believe the line with the mutableStateOf(1) had to reside inside the composable function, so I could not understand how to get it 'outside', i.e global.